# SQL query to get results between 2 tables, and the second one has 3 possibilities of returning data

Tags: mysql, sql

Even though my question was warned as similar title, I couldn't find here any similar problem. Let me explain in details:
I've got two tables (I'm working with MySQL) with these values inserted:

table products:

```
id  name
1   TV
2   RADIO
3   COMPUTER
```

table sales (product_id is A FK which references products(id)):

`id  quantity    product_id
1   50          2
2   100         3
3   200         3`

The tv's haven't been sold, radios got 1 sale (of 50 unities) and computers got two sales (one of 100 e other of 200 unities);

Now I must create a query where I can show the products and its sales, but there are some conditions that make that task difficult:
1 - If there's no sales, show obviously NULL;
2 - If there's 1 sale, show that sale;
3 - If there's more than 1 sale, show the latest sale (which I've tried to use function MAX(id) to make it simple, and yet didn't worked);

In the tables example above, I expect to show this, after a proper SQL Query:

`products.NAME sales.QUANTITY
TV            NULL
RADIO         50
COMPUTER      200`

I've been trying lots of joins, inner joins, etc., but couldn't find the result I expect. Which SQL query can give the answer I expect? 
Any help will be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of your sql query, please?

Comment: I'm using MySQL. You mean the SQL Query I used to try and solve this? It doesn't work.

Comment: MySQL 8.0 implements CTEs. What version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the below query works.

```
SELECT products.name, sl.quantity 
FROM products LEFT JOIN (
SELECT product_id, max(quantity) as quantity FROM sales GROUP BY product_id) sl
ON products.id = sl.product_id
```

Comment: It worked! I'm doing some tests yet, but your query solved the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: Max, Please upvote the answer if you found it helpful. Also mark as correct, if it solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to vote, but I got this message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Thanks Max. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0 you can do:

```
with m (product_id, max_id) as ( -- This is a CTE
  select product_id, max(id) from sales group by product_id
)
select
    p.name,
    s.quantity
  from products p
  left join m on m.product_id = p.id
  left join sales s on s.id = m.max_id
```

If you have an older MySQL, you can use a Table Expression:

```
select
    p.name,
    s.quantity
  from products p
  left join ( -- This is a table expression
    select product_id, max(id) as max_id from sales group by product_id
  ) m on m.product_id = p.id
  left join sales s on s.id = m.max_id
```

Comment: Unfortunely, I'm using MySQL 5 (not by choice).

Comment: Use the latter, then.

Comment: Your SQL query worked. Thanks! Using the latest MySQL version is a call I cannot make at the moment.